# Scaladin Compatibility with Vaadin 7.1.0

Tags: scala, vaadin

Is the current Scaladin 3.0 branch compatible with new Vaadin 7.1.0 release?  My custom Scaladin 3.0 snapshot built from github source results in the following exception after migrating application from Vaadin 7.0.7 to Vaadin 7.1.0

```
Jul 19, 2013 9:17:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [sportzman-internet] in context with path [/sportzman] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not process requests before init() has been called
                at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.requestStart(VaadinService.java:1239)
                at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1318)
                at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:236)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: apparently no - https://github.com/henrikerola/scaladin/blob/3.0/project/Build.scala#L47 says val vaadinVersion = "7.0.5"

Comment: That (7.0.5) should be the version that the Scaladin library is built against.  I have successfully built against 7.0.7 though attempting to build against 7.1.0 introduces a number of compilation errors.

Comment: However, I was hoping that a version of the Scaladin library built against 7.0.7 could still be used in an application using Vaadin 7.1.0.  I suspect the error I'm seeing has something to do with the Vaadin servlet and possible changes to it that need to be reflected in the Scaladin servlet.

Hoping someone else has either addressed the issue or determined that significant work is required to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to update current Scaladin source and rebuild before it can be used with Vaadin 7.1.0

Refer to Scaladin Github repository issue https://github.com/henrikerola/scaladin/issues/25 for pointers on the required modifications.